# Dynamic creation of count table in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a count table from row data with entries separated by tab. For example,

```
Input text file:

   L1 A  A  B  A  C  D
   L2 B  B  D  E  E
   L3 F  G
```

The output I expect is the following table:

```
Output table file:

   A B C D E F G
L1 3 1 1 1 0 0 0
L2 0 2 0 1 2 0 0
L3 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

This is the algorithm I thought about:

1. Create pandas dataframe with col headers ['A','B'..'G']
2. Read text file in with open() by readlines to read line by line
3. Split with tab
4. If col header matches with entry, assign value count ++

Please let me know, if there is a better idea.

Thanks,

AP

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers or explaining why the answers presented don't solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can loop by each row and use `Counter` for dictionaries and last `DataFrame` constructor.

Here `read_csv` should failed if not same lengths of values in each row.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = {row[0]: Counter([x for x in row[1:]]) for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')}

print (d)
{'L2': Counter({'B': 2, 'E': 2, 'D': 1}), 
 'L1': Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}),
 'L3': Counter({'G': 1, 'F': 1})}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').fillna(0).astype(int).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G
L1  3  1  1  1  0  0  0
L2  0  2  0  1  2  0  0
L3  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of hacky way is to use `get_dummies` and `groupby` i.e

For reading the text file we can do

```
df = pd.read_csv('untitled.txt',header=None)
df = df[0].str.split(expand=True).set_index(0)

#This will lead to
#    1  2     3     4     5     6
# 0                               
# L1  A  A     B     A     C     D
# L2  B  B     D     E     E  None
# L3  F  G  None  None  None  None
```

Then we can make use of `pd.get_dummies()`

**Option 1**:

```
dummies= pd.get_dummies(df)
dummies.groupby(dummies.columns.str[-1],axis=1).sum()
```

**Option 2**: (for quickness use stack and value_counts i.e )

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
```

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0                      
L1  3  1  1  1  0  0  0
L2  0  2  0  1  2  0  0
L3  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Great @Bharath.. get_dummies is new to me ! Learning it now !

Comment: Glad can help, you can still vote for the answer right.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a text file like the one you pasted, you can read it with

```
df = pandas.read_table('input.txt', delimiter=' *', 
                       header=None, engine='python', index_col=0)
```

Once you have the DataFrame, you can calculate the counts like this:

```
result = df.apply(pandas.Series.value_counts, axis=1).fillna(0)
```

Which results in this:

```
      A    B    C    D    E    F    G
0                                    
L1  3.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
L2  0.0  2.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0
L3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: I myself have used `series.value_counts` so many times though couldn't think of this for an instant nice one .